# ASP.NET Core AuthorizationHandler not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to add some custom role based `authorisation`, but I am unable to
get the Startup configured to call my `AuthorizationHandler`.

I found some related information on GitHub: [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4656).
Is this a bug or not ?

I am using `ASP.NET Core 3.1` and my initializaion is as follows:

**1:** This retrieves the url/roles from the database using Dapper ORM:

```
private List<UrlRole> GetRolesRoutes()
{
    var urlRole = DapperORM.ReturnList<UrlRole>("user_url_role_all");
    return urlRole.Result.ToList();
}
```

**2:** In my Startup, I get the url/roles and store the result in a global variable:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    this.environment = env;
    UrlRoles = GetRolesRoutes();
}
```

**3:** My Configuration is: **Note** the `UrlRoles` which is passed along

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     // .. snip   
     services.AddAuthorization(o =>
     o.AddPolicy(_RequireAuthenticatedUserPolicy,
            builder => builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser()));

     services.AddAuthorization(options =>
     {
         options.AddPolicy("Roles", policy =>
         policy.Requirements.Add(new UrlRolesRequirement(UrlRoles)));
     });


    services.AddSingleton<AuthorizationHandler<UrlRolesRequirement>, PermissionHandler>();
}
```

**5:** My Handler: which is not being called

```
public class PermissionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UrlRolesRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UrlRolesRequirement urlRolesRequirement)
    {
        var pendingRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.ToList();
        foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
        {
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**6:** My Requirement class:

```
public class UrlRolesRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    private List<UrlRole> UrlRoles { get; }

    public UrlRolesRequirement(List<UrlRole> urlRoles)
    {
        UrlRoles = urlRoles;
    }      
}
```

---

When I debug the `ASP.NET Core` `AuthorizationHandler`, I never see that my custom Requirement as being a requirement, which I configured in the Startup. I expected to see the requirement, and if the requirement is present then the "callback" will happen I assume. But for some reason my configuration fails to add the requirement.

```
public virtual async Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
{
    if (context.Resource is TResource)
    {
        foreach (var req in context.Requirements.OfType<TRequirement>())
        {
            await HandleRequirementAsync(context, req, (TResource)context.Resource);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using your custom policy somewhere? Unless you explicitly require authorization by that policy or unless you make the policy the default, the requirement doesn’t need to be fulfilled, meaning your handler won’t be called.

Comment: @poke can you please give examples.

Comment: Guessing that the problem here could be that you should register your PermissionHandler handler with a dependency on the `IAuthorizationHandler` and not on the `AuthorizationHandler<UrlRolesRequirement>`. Try change it to `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionHandler>();`

Comment: @Dennis1679 If I do that would I not loose the Object being injected? I have updated my question to show how the UrlRoles are retrieved and passed along. The problem is that for some reason the Callback is not happening, and I assume my configuration is incorrect. poke mentioned some options but is not clear on how to fix this yet.

Comment: I am just wondering if MVC is required or can one use Endpoints

Comment: @Wayne you won't lose the UrlRoles. See how [Microsoft themselve](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/62351067ff4c1401556725b401478e648b66acdc/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/AuthorizationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) takes a dependency on IAuthorizationHandler for all of their handlers? What Poke was saying was you need to use the policy that you created because it won't just be doing things on its own. So for example you would add `[Authorize("Roles"]` as an attribute on controller or action level.

Comment: @Dennis1679 Maybe my understating is wrong. I was thinking that instead of decorating each and every controller or action, I rather wanted to have some pre-configuration map in a DB, and then in the pipeline verify the users role or roles which are allocated when the user authenticates. When the user then tries to access a url, the users role gets verified and access is granted or rejected. The Authentication uses JWT. I can get this to work/called: `PermissionHandler : IAuthorizationHandler` but not: `PermissionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UrlRolesRequirement>`

Comment: I think - but I'm not 100% certain - that you can configure the Permission requirement as part of the default policy by creating the policy builder as a variable in AddAuthorization and adding RequireAuthenticatedUser as well as your Permission requirement onto it and then calling .build() on the builder. This would eliminate the need for the [Authorize] tag and by default it would need to statisfy the authentication requirement as well as your permission requirement.

Comment: @Dennis1679 trying to warp my head around this... simply doing services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, [anyname]>(); registers it to be called... then what and why would you do AddAuthorization, simply  registering a DI seems odd that it holds bearing on things ("convention"), is there something that better explains this cozs im confused. I would of thought i would need to link it to something..... its not making much sense.

Comment: @Seabizkit Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding your question. Can you perhaps try rewording it for me? :(

Comment: what i find odd is, that if you register through Di something which implements IAuthorizationHandler directly like `MyClassCat: IAuthorizationRequirement` instead of like `MyClassDog:AuthorizationHandler<AreaAccessRequirement>` where AreaAccessRequirement implements IAuthorizationRequirement, then if you **only** do `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyClassCat>();` MyClassCat will be triggered on every auth call, i was simply saying I do not find this intuitive and was wondering if there was better docs to follow. in other words it was not added to policy's but yet is called.

Answer (score 7):

Anybody in 2022 having this problem with asp.net core on dotnet 6+ ?

The problem I had with my code was that, I registered my handlers without specifying their interface type of "IAuthorizationHandler".
For example:

Instead of doing this: `builder.Services.AddScoped<MustHaveAdminManagementScopeHandler>();`

Do this:

`builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MustHaveAdminManagementScopeHandler>();`

Also, do not register multiple handlers as Singletons. I see the Microsoft docs recommending this, but for some reason, registering multiple `IAuthorizationHandler` as singletons cause an exception.

Comment: Manuals [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0#handler-registration) Creating a class that implements both IAuthorizationRequirement and IAuthorizationHandler removes the need to register the handler in DI because of the built-in PassThroughAuthorizationHandler that allows requirements to handle themselves. ...Unclear how to use it. Handler is not being called even if both interfaces are implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Without telling ASP.NET Core to do so, it will not use your configured policy to authorize anything. Authorization policies are so that you can predefine complex authorization conditions so that you can reuse this behavior when you need it. It however does not apply by default, and it couldn’t considering that you already configure two policies: Which of those should apply? All of them? Then why configure separate policies?

So instead, no policy is being used to authorize a user unless you explicitly tell the framework that. One common method is to use the `[Authorize]` attribute with the policy name. You can put that on controller actions but also on controllers themselves to make all its actions authorize with this policy:

```
[Authorize("Roles")] // ← this is the policy name
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    // …
}
```

If you have a policy that you want to use *most of the times* to authorize users, then you can configure this policy as the default:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
}
```

This for example will define a policy that requires an authenticated users as the default. So whenever you use the `[Authorize]` attribute *without* specificing an explicit policy, then it will use *that* default policy.

This all will still require you to mark your routes somehow that you require authorization. Besides using the `[Authorize]` attribute, you can also do this in a more central location: The `app.UseEndpoints()` call in your `Startup` class.

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")
    .RequireAuthorization("Roles");
```

This is the default route template for controllers but with a call to `RequireAuthorization` which will basically require the `Roles` authorization policy on all routes that match this route template.

You can use also use this place to configure different default authorization policies for your different routes: By splitting up your route template, you can have multiple calls to `MapControllerRoute` with different route templates that all specify their own authorization policy.

> I was thinking that instead of decorating each and every controller or action, I rather wanted to have some pre-configuration map in a DB, and then in the pipeline verify the users role or roles which are allocated when the user authenticates. When the user then tries to access a url, the users role gets verified and access is granted or rejected.

You *could* move the logic how exactly a user is authorized into the authorization handler that verifies your requirement. You would still enable the policy that has this requirement for all the routes you want to test though.

However, I would generally advise against this: Authorization requirements are meant to be simple, and you usually, you want to be able to verify them *without* hitting a database or something other external resource. You want to use the user’s claims directly to make a quick decision whether or not the user is authorized to access something. After all, these checks run on every request, so you want to make this fast. One major benefit of claims based authorization is that you do not need to hit the database on every request, so you should keep that benefit by making sure everything you need to authorize a user is available in their claims.

Comment: I'm transitioning from WebForms to Razor Pages. Your last paragraph made so much sense that it convinced me to give up on trying to use UserManager to check for roles and instead have Identity Server put them on a roles claim in the jwt. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tested solution, which enables `runtime configuration changes`.
Also relieving the burden of decorating each class or action.

In the `Startup` Add the `Role Authorization Requirement`, and also register the
RoleService which will be responsible for ensuring a particular role is authorised to access a particular URL.

Here is the Startup.cs where we configure the requirement and also the role service:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddRequirements(new UrlRolesRequirement())
        .Build();
});

services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>(); // authenticate
services.AddSingleton<IUserRoleService, UserRoleService>();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionHandler>(); // authorise
```

The role IUserRoleService: - the UserRoleService implementation 
validates a users claimed role (a JWT claim) against a configuration map consisting of url/role entries that are allowed, by looking in either in cached map or retrieving the data from the database.

A typical `url(path)` *to* `role` map has the following format, retrieve from  a database, then cached (*if lookups fail, the data is retrieved from the database*):

> ```
> /path/to/resource        ROLE
> ```

```
public interface IUserRoleService
{
    public bool UserHasAccess(ClaimsPrincipal user, string path);
}
```

The Permission handler:

```
public class PermissionHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    private readonly IUserRoleService userRoleService;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

    public PermissionHandler(IUserRoleService userRoleService, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        this.userRoleService = userRoleService;
        this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        var pendingRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.ToList();
        foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
        {
            if (!(requirement is UrlRolesRequirement)) continue;

            var httpContext = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
            var path = httpContext.Request.Path;
            if (userRoleService.UserHasAccess(context.User, path))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                break;
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The RolesRequirement - just a POCO

```
public class UrlRolesRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{           
}
```

Here is a partial implementation of the UserRoleService which validates the JWT role claimed.

```
private bool ValidateUser(ClaimsPrincipal user, string path)
{
    foreach (var userClaim in user.Claims)
    {
        if (!userClaim.Type.Contains("claims/role")) continue;

        var role = userClaim.Value;
        var key = role + SEPARATOR + path;

        if (urlRoles.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            var entry = urlRoles[key];
            if (entry.Url.Equals(path) && entry.Role.Equals(role))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Access denied: " + path);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an immediate 403 response, my custom authorization handler code was never reached. Turns out I forgot to inject them (Scoped is fine). That solved the issue for me.