# Azure App Service - Single AppRole across Services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I have an ASPNET Core Web Site called Web-App-1 and an ASP NET Core Web API called Web-Api-1.

1. There is functionality in Web-Api-1 that I want to secure so that it can only be called by certain users.
2. I also want to know in the Web-App-1 if the current user can call the secure functionality and if not I will not offer them the chance to do so.

I can satify requirement 1 by adding an AppRole to the api's App Registration in AzureAd and checking the ClaimIdentity for that app role.

```
if (this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.HasClaim(
    System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType,
    "SecuredApiFunctionality") == false)
{
    return new UnauthorizedObjectResult("User does not have SecuredApiFunctionality role");
}
```

However when I look in the claims for that user within the context of Web-App-1 I cannot see "SecuredApiFunctionality". I assume this is because it is an AppRole belonging to Web-Api-1 and I am in Web-App-1.

I could define a second AppRole in Web-App-1 and setup priviledges to that too but that sounds like duplication to me. Is there a way of securing the API and the Web App using only one role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't there's other way to achieve what you want other than defining duplicate roles in the `App`.
If you look at [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/tree/main/5-AccessControl/1-call-api-roles), it is how it's done there.
There are also few other resources:

- [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-tutorial/issues/45) for this specific sample
- [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214073/azure-role-based-web-and-api-using-same-app-roles) mentioning similar flow (see comments)

Another approach would be to call the `API` for the user's access token and have his roles there.

**[Edit]:**
To integrate the API call into `Authorize` attribute you can use `IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler`. You can see simple example in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-6.0) or more comprehensive one in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281792/asp-net-core-authorizationhandler-not-being-called).

Comment: How would I integrate the calling of the API into securing the WebSite controller with Authorize attribute on controller actions hiding UI in Views?

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee, sorry for late answer - I edited the post